# Why do avi files not play from windows media player from one drive but do play when copied to another drive?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, avi

I'm running Windows 7 Pro and added a new external USB drive.  I move some avi files over to the drive and now they won't play when I try to play them using Windows Media Player.  If I copy an avi file back to my C drive then the video will play.  I can eliminate missing codecs as the problem since it will play if I copy it back to the original drive.  If I copy it to a different directory on the same drive it will play fine as well.  It will also play fine using media player classic.  I did change the permissions on the folder where I am having problems playing the avi file.  Does Windows Media Player require some specific privileges in order to play avi files?  The error message I get is "Windows Media Player encountered a problem while trying to play the file."

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the read performance of the drives?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, WMP doesn't require any special privileges. It sounds like the permissions of that one folder are just borked. Why not move everything out of this folder into a new folder, and simply remove the original folder? That's probably the easiest fix for a permissions problem.